# Binding parameters with $pdoObject->execute() works but bindValue() doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb, bindvalue

`bindValue()` doesn't work but the query works well if I do hard cording it or use:

```
$pdo->execute([':s_dt'=>$a, ':e_dt'=>$b]);
```

What is the difference between them?

I can't show you some information, so I changed the name of values and tables.

This is the query:

```
select *
from (     
    select *, max(p) as tt
    from  a, c, b 
    where 1=1
            and c.cb=b.cb
            and c.a=b.a
            and dt >= :s_dt
            and dt <= :e_dt
            and a.t = "t"
            and a.s= "1"
            and a.cn= c.cn
            and a.a1=c.a1_n
            and a.a2=c.a2_n                 
            and (b.ct = 1 or b.ct2 = 1 or b.ct3= 1 )
            group by a.ct, a.ct2 a.ct3, a.t, a.a                    
) t
where 1=1
    and (t.p-t.s)  <0                       
    order by d desc , g asc
```

The php code that doesn't work.

```
$query_pdo->bindValue(':s_dt', '2019-10-02', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_pdo->bindValue(':e_dt', '2019-10-10', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_pdo->execute();
```

The other php code that works.

```
$query_pdo->execute([':s_dt'=>'2019-10-02', ':e_dt'=>'2019-10-10']);
```

Comment: are you getting any error message ?

Comment: @Dave this is PDO, not mysqli...

Comment: @체라치에 there is no difference. Your problem is caused by some irrelevant mistake. Please follow the step-by-step example on [how to reproduce the error and debug your PDO code](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve) and you will discover that mistake for sure.